# Apps Script get User's Work Week Settings

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm working on a script to automatically schedule certain tasks for some users at my company. When the tasks get scheduled will be based on the user's workweek and workday, which can be customized in Google Calendar. Most of us have a M-F work week, but we have flexible schedules so for some of us, their work day may be 7-3, others 8-4, or 9-5. Some may work 4 days a week, 10 hours a day so they work Mon-Thur, 7-5, 8-6, or 9-7. That's not counting second shift, third shift, etc. I don't want the tasks to be scheduled outside of their workdays.

How can I access these settings from Apps Script?

Comment: Start by reviewing the [Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar). If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén I reviewed the documentation on Calendar Service before asking the question. The "How to Ask" link you provided states to provide links to similar questions on StackOverflow and how they didn't help. I didn't find any similar questions. Are you suggesting I list and post links to every outside site I've used as well? I don't think a question filled with links that didn't answer my question would be all that helpful to getting it answered. I find being too wordy turns people away, too. It's a straight forward question that I haven't really seen asked anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to get Working Hours information through Calendar API.

Although you can query whether there are conflicting events for a given calendar/time-frame using [Freebusy.query()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/freebusy/query), this method will not return a “busy” response when querying for a time-frame out of working hours.

Additionally, there is currently a new Google API in alpha called [Calendar User Availability API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/user-availability/reference/rest) but it currently only exposes Working Location queries not Working Hours.

More information about Calendar User Availability API on [this blog post](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2022/09/calendar-user-availability-api-beta.html)

Alternatively, you can file a new Feature Request with Google using [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=823906)